# Google Like Paging in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, facebook-c#-sdk, paging

I have been trying since yesterday to get google like paging, but each time i ran into some sort of problem. Finally i got hands on article which is the close match what i want to do but the code is article is broken and even fixing HTML error and other error i cant get i it working can some by change give me a complete link to the google like paging

http://wiki.asp.net/404.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/themes/fan/pages/page.aspx/1537/custom-seo-friendly-paging-in-datalist-like-google/rev/1

I am not sure if the article has source code available i tried to look for it but could not find.

**Answer: I found Great Paging control after two days of work very flexible & customizable**

http://thatstoday.in/a/3831877

Update: Unfortunately, This post has been removed from the link it was not possible to post the code as it had several example of paging with different design themes also. I tried to search for similar code but was not able to find ...

Comment: both of the links are broken.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found answer to my question on the following link

http://thatstoday.in/a/3831877  BROKEN link

Alternative http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/456/custom-seo-friendly-paging-with-aspnet-repeater-or-datalist-control

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667312/Custom-SEO-Friendly-Paging-in-Datalist-like-Google

Answer (score 2):

Andrew, Have you considered using [Yahoo's DataTable](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/).  This provides you with pagination as well as sortable columns, scrolling, row selection, resizeable columns, and inline cell editing.  Here is a javascript example:

```
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(window, "load", function() {
YAHOO.example.ClientPagination = function() {
    var myColumnDefs = [
        {key:"id", label:"ID"},
        {key:"name", label:"Name"},
        {key:"date", label:"Date"},
        {key:"price", label:"Price"},
        {key:"number", label:"Number"}
    ];

    var myDataSource = new YAHOO.util.DataSource("assets/php/json_proxy.php?");
    myDataSource.responseType = YAHOO.util.DataSource.TYPE_JSON;
    myDataSource.responseSchema = {
        resultsList: "records",
        fields: ["id","name","date","price","number"]
    };

    var oConfigs = {
            paginator: new YAHOO.widget.Paginator({
                rowsPerPage: 15
            }),
            initialRequest: "results=504"
    };
    var myDataTable = new YAHOO.widget.DataTable("paginated", myColumnDefs,
            myDataSource, oConfigs);

    return {
        oDS: myDataSource,
        oDT: myDataTable
    };
}();
```

});

Comment: I need to do it in C# and cant use what you have suggested, Thanks anyway. I am surprised to not to find a quality paging control like google as a complete example